# Type mismatch on passing sheetname to procedure

Tags: vba, excel, stored-procedures

I apologize I'm sure I am overlooking something simple but too much time has gone by and I cannot figure out why I cannot pass the worksheet titled `MAIN` as a parameter to the argument of my `Import` procedure below. MAIN is a worksheet within the workbook.

My goal is to have a universal procedure called `Import` where I can pass any worksheet within the same workbook and easily store the below column cell relationships into an array by simply passing the worksheet name as a parameter arguement.

```
Sub Import(sheetname As Worksheet)

'Debug.Print (sheetname)

        cName = "Fund ID"
        cA = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "CUSIP"
    cB = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Description"
    cC = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Security Type"
    cD = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Currency"
    cE = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Price Date"
    cF = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Current Price"
    cG = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Prior Price"
    cH = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Change Price (%)"
    cI = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Change Price (%)"
    cJ = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "BPS Impact"
    cK = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Source"
    cL = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cName = "Comment"
    cM = sheetname.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cName), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column



LastRow = Range("b65000").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To LastRow
            Row = Row + 1
                aRecon1(Row, 1) = CStr(Cells(r, cA)) 'Fund ID ' added string value method
               'aRecon1(Row, 1) = Cells(r, cA)            'Fund ID
                aRecon1(Row, 2) = Cells(r, cB)            'CUSIP
                aRecon1(Row, 3) = Cells(r, cC)            'Description
                aRecon1(Row, 4) = Cells(r, cD)            'Security Type
                aRecon1(Row, 5) = Cells(r, cE)            'Currency
                aRecon1(Row, 6) = Cells(r, cF)            'Price Date
                aRecon1(Row, 7) = Cells(r, cG).Value      'Current Price
                'Debug.Print (Cells(r, cG).Value)
                                                                                    Debug.Print (Cells(r, cG).Value)
                    'Debug.Print (Cells(r, cG))
                aRecon1(Row, 8) = Cells(r, cH).Value      'Prior Price
                aRecon1(Row, 9) = Cells(r, cI)            'Change Price (%)
                aRecon1(Row, 10) = Cells(r, cJ)           'BPS Impact
                aRecon1(Row, 11) = Cells(r, cK)           'Source
                                                                                    Debug.Print (Cells(r, cK))
                aRecon1(Row, 12) = Cells(r, cL)          


    Next r

Sheets("Macro").Activate
```

Comment: How are you actually **calling** this routine?

Comment: You have to pass a worksheet to you procedure, not a worksheet name, ie `Call Import(WorkSheets("MAIN"))` and not `Call Import("MAIN")`

Comment: @Rory Sub Main()

Import "MAIN"

End Sub

Comment: Then see all the other answers. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to pass a worksheet

```
Sub Main()
    GetName ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
End Sub

Function GetName(wb As Worksheet)
    MsgBox wb.Name
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to @Rory's question is important.

In your code you have:

```
Sub Import(sheetname As Worksheet)
```

That's cool *if* you call the Import sub like this (just sample code):

```
For Each oSheet in oWorkbook
    Import oSheet 
Next
```

On the other hand, if you want to call Import like this:

```
strSheet = InputBox("Type the name of the sheet to import")
Import strSheet
```

Then your code needs to be this:

```
Sub Import(sheetname As String)
Dim oSheet as Worksheet
Set oSheet = Sheets(sheetname)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first check your **calling routine**:

```
Sub ROUTINE()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("MAIN")
    Call import(ws)
End Sub
```

is needed.  The following will definitely fail:

```
Sub NotVeryGood()
    Dim ws As String
    ws = "MAIN"
    Call import(ws)
End Sub
```

*(Your Import expects an **Object** rather than the **Name** of the Object)*